# Ошибка при запуске сервера django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Буквально сегодня начал изучать django и возникла ошибка.

В файле settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webexample',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

В файле urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls'))
]
```

Приложение webexample было создано.

При запуске сервера:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\разработка\Сайты\Сайт_1\site_1\site_1\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webexample.urls'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 585, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 570, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 288, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 294, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 334, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 350, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 136, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pathlib.py", line 1314, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pathlib.py", line 1136, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Что делать?

---

Версия python: 3.6.3

### Версия django: 2.2.2

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего  ты забыл создать файл urls.py в приложении webexample.
В корневом urls.py ты ссылаешься на него в строке:
`path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls'))`

Comment: Благодарю, всё заработало!